# Integrated mic not working when headphones (no mic) are plugged in, also some weird static noise in the left headphone

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for 7 days now, and my internal mic isn't working when my headphones (no mic on them) or external speakers are plugged into the headphone jack. I tried looking around in pavucontrol for input on any device, but there is nothing (except monitor devices, which monitor system sound, I think). In pavucontrol, I can choose between microphone (plugged) and internal microphone (unplugged), but neither gets any input, except microphone (plugged in) getting constant noise recording that wasn't affected by my voice.

Another thing is that, only on Ubuntu, my left headphone is making static noise, and that's only while playing sound in the right stereo channel. If playing sound only through the left channel, the left headphone works normally. When I plug them into my phone, or earlier on Windows on the same laptop, they work normally, without any static noise. The same thing happens on my external speakers, but it's much much less noticeable and I can hear it only in a few specific songs.

To summarize what I've tried:

- Using a live Linux Pop!_OS 20.10, and the same problems seem to appear.
- Checking if there was any input on any device in pavucontrol when my headphones were plugged in, found none.
- Tried to do put my laptop to sleep, plug in the headphones, and then wake the computer, as an online thread suggested. It didn't work.
- Random terminal commands I found online.
- Rebooting.

My sound card should be Intel 100 series/C230, and this is my system probe on linux-hardware.org https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=99e25d58ad The same site says that my sound card is supported on Linux, so I'm hoping this can be solved.

Thanks in advance, means a lot!